# Javascript function returning "cannot read property length of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to create a function that takes an array containing nested arrays and a number. The array I'm using as a parameter represents the times at which different students showed up to a class, each nested array is a set of times. The number represents the minimum of students that need to show up for the class to begin. The values inside each nested array are numbers, these numbers need to be either 0 or a negative. If the amount of 0's and negatives is equal to or larger to the number of students required for the class to start, then the function should push a true boolean into an array which the function will be returning later. If there aren't enough students, it has to push a false boolean into the same array. So if we have 3 nested arrays, the first containing enough students, and the two others don't, the return should end up being [true, false, false].
This is what I've written so far:

```js
function openings (arrayOfTimes, studentsRequired){
    const openWhen = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= arrayOfTimes.length; i++){ 
        var x = arrayOfTimes[i]; 
        for (let j = 0; j <= x.length; j++){ 
            let y = x[i]; 
            let z = [];
            if (y <= 0){
                z.push(y);
            }
            let open = true; 
            if (z.length >= studentsRequired){ 
                openWhen.push(open);
            }
            let notOpen = false;
             if (z.length < studentsRequired){
                openWhen.push(notOpen);
            }
        }
    }
    return openWhen;
}

console.log(openings([[1,2,0],[0,0,-1],[-2,-3,0]],2));
```

The output says "cannot read property length of undefined", seeing the error log it indicates that the undefined property is x.

This is my first time using both nested arrays and a for loop within another for loop. I appreciate any insight and explanation on where I went wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the error is about `x.length`, then at least one item in `arrayOfTimes` isn't an Array or array-like object unto itself and doesn't have a `length`. You should edit your question and show how you are calling `openings` and the data you are passing to it.

Comment: @scrappedcola Please don't ask for code to be posted to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Executable code can be placed right inside of a question here with a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've edited it to show how I'm calling it.

Comment: Please update it again with enough code to reproduce the error in question. At this point, we get `"Uncaught ReferenceError: esteIngreso is not defined"`

Comment: @ScottMarcus it appears i'm behind in the times. noted

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm sorry, I'm not a native english speaker and I've translated the variable names to be more readable and missed that one. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your for loops, you are using `i <= arrayOfTimes.length` and `j <= x.length`. If you change these loops to use `i < arrayOfTimes.length` and `j < x.length`, they will work properly. Keep in mind that the first element of an array has an index of `0`, meaning the length of the array will always be 1 more than the maximum index of an array.

I've re-written the function to be a bit simpler, and I've tested it. It returns a boolean for each sub-array, true if the sub-array contains at least the minimum number of values less than 1.

```js
function openings (timesArray, minimum) {
   return timesArray.map((times) => {
      return times.filter(time => time < 1).length >= minimum;
   });
}
```

Your sample input

```js
console.log(openings([[1,2,0],[0,0,-1],[-2,-3,0]],2));
// returns [ false, true, true ]
```

Comment: Doing that I'm still getting the same error message. Any clue on why that may be happening? Thank you!

Comment: @LuisArgüelles check my answer

Comment: you may need to reload the page, IDE, etc. that you're working with. i know it sounds stupid, but honestly i forget to do this myself a lot.

Comment: I've doubled checked, it works but now I'm getting individual results for each value inside of each nested array. I need to have one boolean per nested array. I don't really know if it's an issue with my source code, my explanation or if the solution you've provided just closely missed it. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this questions, so if you can help me with this it'd mean a lot.

Comment: I think I found the answer looking at the code, I'm accepting your answer! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey I double checked, and the error I mentioned is still showing up, I thought I could have solved it but I'm still running into the same wall. What I need is my code to return a true or false value for each nested array instead of the values inside the nested arrays. Right now I'm getting 9 booleans instead of 3. I feel really bad about further bothering you but I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now and it is really setting me back. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217844/discussion-between-harrison-smith-and-luis-arguelles).

Comment: @LuisArgüelles i've re-written the function. i tested your input, and some other inputs and it works now.